# "View [auth.emails.password] not found.",

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, boilerplate, laravel-authorization

I'm trying to test the recovry method in laravel-api-boilerplate-jwt but when I use postman and input email and post it to `http://localhost:8000/api/auth/recovery` it returns

```
{
"message": "View [auth.emails.password] not found.",
"status_code": 500
}
```

does anyone know why? I don't think I need a view because this is an api for a mobile app! Or is three anything I need to configure to make it work?

link to the framework :

```
https://github.com/francescomalatesta/laravel-api-boilerplate-jwt
```

Comment: Sending an email loads the the blade view/template associated with that email.  You would need to create `resources/views/auth/emails/password.blade.php` for the email template.

Comment: thank you. but what should the view consist of ? is there something I have to refer to ? or a variable to include?

Comment: The view will be the content of the email you are sending.  See https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail

Comment: do I also need to create a view for reset password? when I get the password reset link from Laravel api, it opens  **NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:**. how does that work for api ? thank you for your answers

Comment: I would recommend creating an issue with the boilerplate you are using as these are all issues regarding the boiler plate

Comment: I think I found a solution for this. Since I got an email with a token in it ,I'll add text fields in my mobile app where users input password+password_confirmation+email+token from email. These will be sent to reset function in laravel and laravel will release a new token for the new login info.

Answer (score 0):

if you use version 5.2 the error is in the auth.php file of the config folder. change to this confiture

```
'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'email' => 'auth.emails.password', // here you change the path by 'emails.password'
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],
```